# What are some ways to strengthen one's content generation muscle, besides freewriting?

Tags: content-generation

To be able to generate ample content for a simple containing thought, to my mind seems better than confinement to the uttermost brevity. For to me this seems needful for writing abundantly on a topic, because, whether it be a mundane or majestic one, if the memory and thinking of a writer is weak, without the desire of research within them, they can yield no writing of any sufficient length. Therefore I ask you, not concerning what theme to write about, but concerning how to expound on a theme having already been determined, besides freewriting, how can they strengthen their muscle sufficiently for the generation of content, so that at length they may write about anything, whether mundane or majestic, having not the need to do any research?

Comment: What language do you write in? Because your writing may need significant English language editing...We say: automatic writing, yes. We don't say "freewriting".

Comment: I think you need to be clearer on what you actually want: what kind of writing you want to do and why can't you do it now? Just being able to write at length is valueless unless you have something to say (and an audience willing to read it). What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Further to Lambie's and Stuart F's Comments, can you say why you can't ask colleagues to review what you wrote?

Answer (score 3):

Some science based techniques to enhance creativity:

- Do not judge, evaluate or censor your ideas. As soon as you try to only have "good" or "appropriate" ideas, you obstruct the flow.
- Reduce distraction.
- Practice mindfulness or meditation.
- Go outside, if possible into nature, instead of staring at electronic devices.
- Exercise (sports) or at least move. Physical activity enhances cognitive performance and creativity.
- Sleep well and enough and while it's dark.
- Be in a good mood.
- Do not work against a deadline.
- Interact with different kinds of people instead of staying inside your social comfort zone.
- Interest yourself in different fields of knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot upvote it because I don't believe in mindfulness meditation.

Comment: @garbia You mean, you cannot upvote an answer because you only find nine out of ten suggestions useful to you?!? That is like saying you don't want to eat in a restaurant because you don't like every meal on the menu. —— I can understand if you say that you have tried mindfulness and it doesn't work for you, fair enough, but mindfulness is proven to work for many people: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness#Scientific_research. Of course it doesn't work for everyone, just like any other tip or trick doesn't work for everyone equally well.

Comment: Your advice is sound but not sure how much of it is specifically related to writing.

Comment: I have no problem with creativity in all its meanderings. But thanks for the link!

Comment: I think my first comment was very clear. Your advice applies to any endeavor, but it is not about writing itself.

Comment: I said it already: It does not apply to writing specifically. It is general self-help. Which is fine.